# How to prevent automatic insertion of a blank line at the beginning of a `justify` environment of `ragged2e` package?

Tags: ragged2e

Blank line is always generated at the beginning for some reason. I need to get rid of it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[draw,text width=3cm]
            {\begin{justify}this is just some text this is just some text this is just some text\end{justify}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use node option `align` with value `justify`. Then you do not need package `ragged2e`.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[draw,text width=3cm,align=justify]
            {this is just some text this is just some text this is just some text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use command `\justifying` (provided by package `ragged2e`) inside the node text. But then you have to use a `\par` at the end of the text.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[draw,text width=3cm,align=justify]
            {\justifying this is just some text this is just some text this is just some text\par};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not see a difference. But you can try my second suggestion: `\justifying ... \par` inside the node text.